# acra - send custom message

Tags: android, acra

I tried to send a custom data with acra(and without crashing my app) with these 2 lines

```
ACRA.getErrorReporter().putCustomData("myKey", "myValue");
ACRA.getErrorReporter().handleException(null);
```

But in the report that I received was just:

```
Report requested by developer
```

The problem is that in my report there was no "myKey" or "myValue". How can I fix that? Maybe the problem is that I didn't include some specific Report Fields?

After that I tried with just

```
ACRA.getErrorReporter().handleException(null);
```

and it worked as with 2 lines above??

Answer (score 0):

ACRA is designed to capture unhandled exceptions. It also provides functionality to silently send handled exceptions. Sending null is way outside its design parameters.

Try sending  an actual exception.

Comment: Crashlytics has that option

Comment: this is what I looked for: ACRA.getErrorReporter().handleException(new RuntimeException("Error"));

Comment: ACRA.getErrorReporter().putCustomData("myKey", "myValue"); This actually works but this field has to be added: ReportField.CUSTOM_DATA

Answer (score 0):

I did a little workaround to group specific messages sent by it's exception. I introduced "FakeException" and removed stack trace so the message would be smaller.

```
public class FakeException extends Exception {
    @Override
    public Throwable fillInStackTrace() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void setStackTrace(StackTraceElement[] trace) {
        super.setStackTrace(null);
    }
}
```

Now You can create another Exception that extends FakeException and do something like this:

```
public void SendUserReport(String reportText){
    ACRA.getErrorReporter().putCustomData(USER_REPORT_CONTENT_TAG, reportText);
    ACRA.getErrorReporter().handleSilentException(new NotificationFromUserFakeException());
    ACRA.getErrorReporter().removeCustomData(USER_REPORT_CONTENT_TAG);
}
```

The following picture shows this report in Acralyzer (awesome software, definitely use it).

[image: Fake exception report]